# Initialize String[] with empty strings

Tags: java, arrays, string

I want to create a String array containing multiple empty strings.

```
String[] array = {"", "", "", "", ""};
```

In python we could achieve this simply with this code  `[""] * 5`.
Is there something similar for java?

Comment: Isn't this code working?

Comment: @FarhanQasim the code is working. But if I want to initialize an array with 100 empty strings I don't want to write it by hand...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing syntactic, no.

At an API level, there's `Arrays.fill`, but sadly it doesn't *return* the array you pass it, so you can't use it in the initializer, you have to use it after:

```
String[] array = new String[5];
Arrays.fill(array, "");
```

You could always roll-your-own static utility method of course.

```
public static <T> T[] fill(T[] array, T value) {
    Arrays.fill(array, value);
    return array;
}
```

then

```
String[] array = YourNiftyUtilities.fill(new String[5], "");
```

---

(Obviously, it would probably be dodgy to do that with mutable objects, but it's fine with String.)

Comment: Thanks exactly what I was looking for. 
Can you elaborate your second statement a bit more?
Why shouldn't I use this with mutable objects?

Comment: @JohnyDoe: Because every entry in the array will refer to the **same** object. With mutable objects, that's not usually what you want (although it certainly *can* be), since you usually don't want `array[0].property = value` to mean that `array[1].property` now has that value (because `array[0]` and `array[1]` refer to the same object). But Strings are immutable (modulo unreasonable games with reflection) so there's no such concern here.

Answer (score 2):

With Java 8, you have a not-so-concise, yet better-than-repeated-literals idiom:

```
// will create a String[] with 42 blank Strings
String[] test = Stream
    // generate an infinite stream with a supplier for empty strings
    .generate(() -> "")
    // make the stream finite to a given size
    .limit(42)
    // convert to array with the given generator function to allocate the array
    .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`fill`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object-) method from the `Arrays` class.

```
String[] test = new String[10];
Arrays.fill(test, "");
```

Comment: Duplicate answer, now? Also, it's `Arrays`, no?

Comment: @CodeFinity fixed it. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment:  And for completeness, the import is: `import java.util.Arrays;`

Answer (score 1):

The closest would be

```
String[] array = new String[5];
Arrays.fill(array, "");
```

however it's not strictly the same as the `array` would first be initialised with `null` values.

Answer (score 1):

You could try cycle:

```
String[] array = new String[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    array[i] = "";
```

Comment: Bad idea to hardcode the `5` in two different places.

Comment: Better use `array.length`.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to use `IntStream.rangeClosed` to generate the required amount of strings.

```
String[] result = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 5)
                           .mapToObj(i -> "")
                           .toArray(String[]::new);
```